# Running functions inside of a view Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a view that returns all the bookings that are between a certain date. I have a table called Booking which includes the columns:

```
startDate date,
noOfDays int,
```

and more columns which aren't relevant to the view I'm trying to create.

I'm trying to run the following query to create a view but it seems to fail with the error **"ORA-00904: "DATEADD": Invalid identifier"**

```
CREATE VIEW Present_bookings AS 
SELECT * FROM Booking 
WHERE startDate => '2018-03-12' 
AND startDate <= DATEADD(Booking.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', Booking.noOfDays);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that `DATE_ADD` is an Oracle function

Comment: DATEADD is unknown. Is it a function that is supposed to be in your schema?

Comment: Syntax DateAdd (Date, Format, Days, Months, Years)

Comment: @dnoeth it seems to be a function included in oracle https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Dateadd.html

Comment: @YashMorar that's a MySQL reference (MySQL is owned by Oracle)

Comment: @SumeshTG my syntax follows this, looking at the oracle docs it should work

Comment: @DavidFaber: The link is for *Document Automation Language (DAL)*, but still not an Oracle function.

Comment: @DavidFaber I believe I am using MySQL (it's hard to tell as this is all being done through a terminal at my university computer)

Comment: You're getting an Oracle error so you're using Oracle, not MySQL

Comment: Step 1: Run the SELECT stand-alone, not as part of CREATE VIEW. What happens?

Comment: Your error code `ORA-00904` implies running Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is not correct. **All startdate is less than startdate+5 days**. Are you sure about this condition? If yes, then it will be simplied as:

```
CREATE VIEW Present_bookings AS 
select  *
FROM Booking
where startDate >= to_date('2018-03-12','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

OR probably you are thinking about this:

```
CREATE VIEW Present_bookings AS 
select  *
FROM Booking
where startDate between to_date('2018-03-12','YYYY-MM-DD') 
  and to_date('2018-03-17','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Ah yes you're right. My stupidity! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it and/or upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your query. But the primary thing is that `DATEADD()` is not a valid function in Oracle. Oracle date arithmetic is very simple; just add `noOfDays` to `startDate`:

```
CREATE VIEW Present_bookings AS 
SELECT * FROM Booking 
 WHERE startDate >= DATE'2018-03-12' 
   AND startDate <= startDate + noOfDays;
```

Note that I changed your operator `=>` to `>=` and added the `DATE` keyword to the date literal `2018-03-12` to tell Oracle that it's a date.

As an aside, I don't know what the second condition is supposed to do; `startDate` should always be less than `startDate + noOfDays` unless `noOfDays` is negative. I think you might want something like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW Present_bookings AS 
SELECT * FROM Booking 
 WHERE startDate <= DATE'2018-03-12'
   AND DATE'2018-03-12' <= startDate + noOfDays;
```

OR

```
CREATE VIEW Present_bookings AS 
SELECT * FROM Booking 
 WHERE DATE'2018-03-12' BETWEEN startDate AND startDate + noOfDays;
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the DATE'2018-03-12' notation. How do you specify the date format for this?

Comment: It's an ANSI date literal - `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Thank you David! I also realised my mistakes with the operation signs, and the fact that startDate is always less that startDate+5...

Comment: Also, if you really want **present** bookings, use `SYSDATE` in place of the date constant

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a easy way to add a number of days to a date.
Try using `interval` here:

```
select sysdate, sysdate + interval '5' day as "FUTURE"  from dual;
=> 
SYSDATE                 FUTURE
22.03.2018 14:37:27     27.03.2018 14:37:27
```

Take care of the `'5'` as a character, not a number.
This also works with years, months (take care of 29.02 here) etc.